# Generation and transmission of electricity

Tags: power, three-phase

According to my textbook the three phase power is generated so that the power that is needed to generate electricity by the torque remain constant. Another reason is that the summation of the three signals are zero so only one return wire is needed when the loads are equal. Therefore, the number of wires get decreased from 6 to 4.

I have some questions about the basics of generating and transmitting electricity.

1- I don't see how can we assume that the loads are equal when that depends on the users and the number of appliances that they use.

2- So the electricity is generated and transmitted as three phase, could someone explain to me in one form it enters our home.

Comment: Have you studied Delta-Wye connections yet? That would help your understanding.

Comment: The loads are balanced as wel as can be.  If only one phase is allocated for a house then adjacent houses will use the other phases.  In a street the average per phase should be reasonably well balanced.  If a house is connected for three phase it is expected that the (fixed) loads in the house are distributed across the three phases as well as can be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The number of users connected to one generator is high and divided among the three phases about equally. The result is approximately equal usage from each phase. Large buildings and factories have three-phase service. A high percentage of their connected equipment is three-phase motors. The motors are balanced three-phase loads. The load at the supply generator is therefore fairly well balanced. The generator will tolerate some imbalance.
2. Electricity enters our homes from a single-phase transformer that is connected between one phase and neutral. It reduces the voltage to the home voltage level of about 240 volts. In the USA, that is divided into two 120 volt parts for wall plugs. Both parts are used for larger loads like electric stoves, water heaters, and central air conditioners. More than one house is connected to each transformer. There will be two other transformers in the same neighborhood connected to the other two phases.

The following picture shows three phase lines on three insulators at the top of the pole at the top right of the picture. The neutral wire is on a small insulator a short distance down the pole. At the next pole, three wires going down the pole are connected to the three phase wires. I believe that those three wires go under the ground to connect high voltage from a small wind generation system on the other side of the road. The poles that go on down the road have only one phase wire and a neutral wire. Near the bottom of the picture towards the left, you can see a transformer mounted on a pole. That supplies single phase power to one or more local users.

[image]

Comment: So the transformation from three phase to single phase occurs at the substation?

Comment: The transformer from the local distribution level to 240 volts is closer than the substation, at the top of a pole, in a locked box on the ground or underground. The separation of the three transmission lines may take place at the substation or closer.

Comment: I see that your profile page shows that you are in Canada. The electrical supply systems in Canada are very similar to the system in the US.

Comment: The substation will output three-phase power on three "hot" wires, one for each phase, plus a neutral/ground.  In the distribution system, users wanting single-phase power will only connect to one of the three "hot" wires and to the neutral/ground.  You could say that conversion from three-phase to single phase occurs randomly throughout the distribution system, wherever a customer wants single-phase power.

Answer (score 1):

> three phase power is generated so that the power that is needed to generate electricity by the torque remain constant
>
> 1- I don't see how can we assume that the loads are equal when that depends on the users and the number of appliances that they use.

I think you are misinterpreting the text book. The point that is being made is that the torque is constant over one single revolution of the axis of the generator/motor, not necessarily over long periods. Because of the three phase engine the torque at any given angle of the axis is constant for a given three phase load. This results in low vibrations and low acoustic noise. Using vector math you can prove that for any angle the field amplitude of a three phase system is constant.

This is different for a single phase machine, then the torque is eg. maximum at 0 and 180 degrees and minimum at 90 and 270 degrees. This potentially results in vibrations (=loss).

Comment: With three phases 120 degrees apart there is no point where they are all at zero voltage.  This means that there is some torque exerted at all times and the ripple frequency is 3 times the line frequency (180 Hz in USA, 150 Hz in South Africa, UK etc) causing ledd vibration.

Answer (score 1):

The way it enters our home depends heavily on the country we talk about.

In many countries, there is indeed only one phase and the neutral wire going into a house.

In others, e. g. Germany, there are even three phases running into the flat (plus N and PE). Here the phases are divided up to the circuit breakers: the first one gets L1, the second one L2, the third one L3, the fourth L1 again etc. If we have an electric stove, it gets connected to three phases. Often, two burners/elements of the range are connected to one phase (e. g. the left two and the right two), which makes 2 phases for cooking. The third phase is for the oven.

This also mostly holds for cases where the range and the oven don't form a combined unit, but are separated.

Comment: By "flames" are you referring to circular heating elements on top of the oven, used to heat food in a pot or pan?  Those are called "burners" in American English, regardless of whether they consume electricity or gas.  (Also, the entire machine is called a "stove" in AmEng - "oven" refers only to what you're calling the "baking oven part.")

Comment: In South Africa (and likely England and other ex-colonies) the cooking thing has 'hot-plates' or 'elements' and together forms the 'range'  The baking part is the 'oven'.  If the 'oven' and 'range' are a combined unit it is called a 'stove'.